# Unable to connect - docker

Tags: python, docker

I am learning docker and try to dockerize a simple fastapi app.
Here is my docker file

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt -U --no-cache-dir

COPY fast.py .

CMD [ "uvicorn","fast:app","--host","127.0.0.1","--port","8000" ]
```

Every thing work well when i build and run. I can see packages getting installed.
I can also see uvicorn running
`Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)`
but when i click on url. It say Unable to connect in browser.

I think there is an issue with my dockerfile, but i am unable to figure it out
**Edit:**
docker build command
`docker build -t fastapi .`
and docker run command
`docker run fastapi`
I am not using docker compose.
Here is result of docker `ps -a`
[image]

Full code structure
-Dockerfile
-fast.py
-requirements.txt

Here is code of `fast.py`

```
from typing import Union
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

What I have tried. I added `EXPOSE 8000` in Dockerfile and also tried `docker run -p 8000:8000 fastapi` But nothing work

Comment: Could you please also share the command (eg docker run ...) or the docker-compose.yml you are using ?

Comment: @ΒΑΣΙΛΗΣΧΑΡΛΑΥΤΗΣ added

Comment: @TalhaAnwar Very detailed question. Please try my edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the picture posted it seems like you didn't expose the ports.

The ports are exposed from your docker to your pc, in this instance, when you iniate the container not in the Dockerfile

Try the following

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 fastapi
```

**EDIT**

You also should try changing the way you start the fast api app in the container

From

```
CMD [ "uvicorn","fast:app","--host","127.0.0.1","--port","8000" ]
```

To

```
CMD [ "uvicorn","fast:app","--host","0.0.0.0","--port","8000" ]
```

In the first version you have passed the loopback interface.

**But you can't do that**. The loopback interface inside a container means "only this container", just like on the host means "only this host". If a service is binding to 127.0.0.1 then there is no way -- from your host or from another container -- to reach that service.

***Caveat** This holds true, assuming you dont change the network settings of the container e.g. --network host*

**TL;DR**

Change the host from `looback` interface and when you run your `container`  `expose` the port 8000

Answer (score 0):

When you run your container, you need to specify the port you want to "publish" your app.

```bash
docker run -p "8000:8000" fastapi
```

The upper command instructs docker to map the host port 8000 to container port 8000.

You can find more info in this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).

You may find easier to use [docker-compose.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

```bash
version: "3.8"
services:
  fastapi:
    build: . #you can use any directory but it is recommended to be putted together with Dockerfile in the root of your project.
    ports:
      - "8000:8000" # left the (local)host port, right the Dockerfile "EXPOSE" (in this case also uvicorn ... -p xxxx) port.
```

Please read the comments as I use them in order to help you better understand the parts of docker-compose file.

In oreder to run your app you can use:

```bash
docker compose up -d
```

Or

```bash
docker-compose up -d
```

If you are questioning yourself which version of the upper command you need to use, it depends on what kind of docker compose have you installed in your machine.

I personally recommend the [plugin version](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/compose-plugin/) (first option), as it feels more docker native.

EDIT: As @tolis-gerodimos suggested you need to change the listening IP from `"127.0.0.1" (localhost)` to `"0.0.0.0" (any)`. This is a wide used practice in all languages/frameworks/tools as it reduces the complexity during the deployment.

Answer (score -1):

You did not exposed the port on your dockerfile,

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt -U --no-cache-dir

COPY fast.py .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "uvicorn","fast:app","--host","127.0.0.1","--port","8000" ]
```

Make sure to remove the container and build the image again.

Also, make sure you expose the port on your host in your docker run command.

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 fastapi
```

The left 8000 will be the host (your computer) and the right one will be the destination (the container itself)

Comment: did not worked. same error

Comment: Publish your docker build & docker run cmd, also check docker ps to see what ports are exposed.

Comment: I see you tried adding ports on dockerfile and docker run command. Please try to remove the container and build the image again, it might be a caching issue.